# Siunitx table with significance stars not working

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table with significance stars built via the command `^{***}` (i.e. math mode). I recently found out that `\sym{***}` could also be used. I don't know which is better, would be nice if someone can explain. The main goal however is to make the simple table of the MWE below compile without errors.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, 
    input-decimal-markers = {.},
    input-symbols = ()}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            l*{3}{S[table-align-text-post = false]}
            }

            \hline
            XYZ & -100.00^{***} & -80.15^{**} & -20.15^{*} \\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It always says 'Missing $ inserted'. Not sure what to do here. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Did you try with `XYZ & -100.00*** & -80.15** & -20.15* \\ `?

Comment: @leandriis just now, that also doesn't work. Now it says 'Misplaced \noalign. \end

Comment: What are those `$... $`  doing in those cells? S columns are already math mode

Comment: @ghx: Did you make sure to end your line with a `\\ `? It is missing in your code.

Comment: @leandriis thanks, I added the linebreak `\\\`. daleif Removed, thank you. Unfortunately it still does not work. Now it says  'Missing $ inserted'

Comment: @ghx: Either try completely without the superscript, or use `XYZ & -100.00$^{***}$ & -80.15$^{**}$ & -20.15$^{*}$ \\ `. `^{...}` alone does not work in `S` type columns. If you prefer, you can also use a custom command for the stars, such as `\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}` and `\sym{*}` (See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180001/134144 or `\protected\def\stars#1{$^{#1}$}` and `\stars{*}` (See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181394/134144)

Comment: @leandriis thanks a lot, that's more than one working solution. Not using a superscript looks bad in my opinion, but for instance `XYZ & -100.00$^{***}$ & -80.15$^{**}$ & -20.15$^{*}$` works perfectly fine with siunitx. If you want to make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code, I have used the `\sym` command (`\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}`) in order to get superscript stars in `S` type columns. I have also used appropriate `table-format` settings for the three `S` type columns to get less horizontal white space between them. To reserve some space for the stars, I have used the `table-space-text-post` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{group-separator = {,}, 
    input-decimal-markers = {.},
    input-symbols = ()}

\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-align-text-post = false, table-space-text-post=\sym{***}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            lS[table-format=-3.2]*{2}{S[table-format=-2.2]}
            }

            \hline
            XYZ & -100.00\sym{***} & -80.15\sym{**} & -20.15\sym{*} \\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Other alternatives to typeset the stars include the use of `$^{*}$` or the `\stars{**}` command [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181390/formatting-in-a-regression-result-table/181394#181394)